# Two divs and floated button

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to make 2 divs (one with a adaptive size) display side by size  with a third that will float below the first column at the bottom of the content,  however I am having problems with the floating div displaying where it should.

This is how I want it to look:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: table
}

.header-text {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cart-pos {
  display: table-cell; 
  float: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 36.5%;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.cart-pos img {
  margin: 19px 0 15px 15px;
}

.ui-accordion-header .accordion-button, .ui-accordion-header .accordion-button-active {
  background-color: #5fa0d8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active .accordion-button-active {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #3570af;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="header-text"><h3>Product Name</h3>

<h4>Subheader text</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.</p></div>

<div class="cart-pos">
<div><a class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text"></a></div>
<p><a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; margin: 0px 4% 0 0; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://www.webpage.co.uk"><strong>SUBSCRIBE</strong></a>

<a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://webpage.co.uk"><strong>PURCHASE</strong></a></p>
</div>

<div class="accordion-button">Find out More ▸</div><div style="display: none;" class="accordion-button-active">Less ▾</div>

</div>
```

Bear in mind the order of the HTML is important as it needs to display in the correct order at smaller viewports:

Comment: Is there a reason for you to be using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you suggestions guys, but none of these solutions will work the way I need.

Instead, I have added the accordion buttons under the

tag as some of you suggested (which I was already aware of prior to this, but didn't do as it caused stacking issues at smaller viewports).

I have also added another set of accordion buttons (with the classes of accordion-button accordion-button-mob and accordion-button-active accordion-button-active-mob) where I wanted them to appear at the bottom for the small viewport, using css to display/ hide depending on the screen resolution.

This solution isn't neat, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the place of `Find out More` after the `p` tag

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: table
}

.header-text {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cart-pos {
  display: table-cell; 
  float: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 36.5%;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.cart-pos img {
  margin: 19px 0 15px 15px;
}

.ui-accordion-header .accordion-button, .ui-accordion-header .accordion-button-active {
  background-color: #5fa0d8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active .accordion-button-active {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #3570af;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="header-text"><h3>Product Name</h3>

<h4>Subheader text</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.</p><div class="accordion-button">Find out More ▸</div></div>

<div class="cart-pos">
<div><a class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text"></a></div>
<p><a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; margin: 0px 4% 0 0; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://www.webpage.co.uk"><strong>SUBSCRIBE</strong></a>

<a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://webpage.co.uk"><strong>PURCHASE</strong></a></p>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" class="accordion-button-active">Less ▾</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Having the Find out more button here causes it to be in the wrong order when stacked at small viewports.  It must be in the order of Text, Image and then button underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you out. Just use `display:flex`. It will help a lot and helps to avoid floats.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.header-text {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.cart-pos {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cart-pos img {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-accordion-header .accordion-button, .ui-accordion-header .accordion-button-active {
  background-color: #5fa0d8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active .accordion-button-active {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #3570af;
}

.btn-group {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="header-text"><h3>Product Name</h3>

<h4>Subheader text</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.</p>
<div class="accordion-button">Find out More ▸</div>
</div>

<div class="cart-pos">
<div><a class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text"></a></div>
<div class="btn-group"><a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; margin: 0px 4% 0 0; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://www.webpage.co.uk"><strong>SUBSCRIBE</strong></a>

<a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://webpage.co.uk"><strong>PURCHASE</strong></a></div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" class="accordion-button-active">Less ▾</div>

</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned before, having the 'Find out More' button within the header text div causes it to stack in the wrong order when viewed at smaller viewports.  At 480px it switches to a stacked view with each column at 100% and MUST display in this oder: Text, Image, Find out More button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this..and it will work only in desktop site..not in mobile site

```
.accordion-button {
        position: absolute;
        left: 11px;
    }
```

```css
.accordion-button {
 position: absolute;
 left: 11px;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  display: table
}

.header-text {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cart-pos {
  display: table-cell; 
  float: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 36.5%;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.cart-pos img {
  margin: 19px 0 15px 15px;
}

.ui-accordion-header .accordion-button, .ui-accordion-header .accordion-button-active {
  background-color: #5fa0d8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active .accordion-button-active {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #3570af;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="header-text"><h3>Product Name</h3>

<h4>Subheader text</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.</p></div>

<div class="cart-pos">
<div><a class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text"></a></div>
<p><a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; margin: 0px 4% 0 0; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://www.webpage.co.uk"><strong>SUBSCRIBE</strong></a>

<a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://webpage.co.uk"><strong>PURCHASE</strong></a></p>
</div>

<div class="accordion-button">Find out More ▸</div><div style="display: none;" class="accordion-button-active">Less ▾</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule from an accessibility perspective, it's best to have tabs be what they really are which is why I've used buttons rather than styled `<a>` tags.

I've used `flex-box` which handles the proportions and position for you. I've put a width limit of 800px on if it expands forever it becomes difficult for a user to read it.

Here is a link to my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vzmf032/), in case you want to play with the code.

```css
/* banner is the whole banner */
.banner {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 0px #888 solid;
  border-width: 4px 0;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

/* content is the left hand side */
.banner .content {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.banner .content h2 {
  color: #5fa0d8;
}

.banner .content h4 {
  color: #444;
}

.banner .content p {
  color: #888;
}

.banner .content button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 0;
  background: #5fa0d8;
  border: solid #5fa0d8 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* options is the right hand side */
.banner .options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner .options .buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.banner .options .buttons button {
  flex: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: solid #5fa0d8 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5fa0d8;
  max-width: calc(50% - 3px);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Product Name</h2>
    <h4>Subheader text</h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.
    </p>
    <button class="accordian">Find out More ></button>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text">
    </a>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>subscribe</button>
      <button>purchace</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `display:table-cell` in header

```css
   .header {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.header-text {
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cart-pos {
  display: table-cell; 
  float: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 36.5%;
  clear: both;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.cart-pos img {
  margin: 19px 0 15px 15px;
}

.ui-accordion-header .accordion-button, .ui-accordion-header .accordion-button-active {
  background-color: #5fa0d8;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.ui-accordion-header-active .accordion-button-active {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #3570af;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

<div class="header-text"><h3>Product Name</h3>

<h4>Subheader text</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei meliore volumus legendos ius, quis homero eu quo. Duo democritum consectetuer comprehensam ne, minim docendi quaerendum eam in. Decore docendi ex eam, cu iisque lucilius inciderint mea. No sed illud everti. Eros utroque an usu, mel noster nostrud detraxit at, cu sed veniam mollis omittam.</p></div>

<div class="cart-pos">
<div><a class="colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="alt text"></a></div>
<p><a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; margin: 0px 4% 0 0; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://www.webpage.co.uk"><strong>SUBSCRIBE</strong></a>

<a style="display: block; width: 46%; text-align: center; border: 2px solid #5fa0d8; float: left; padding: 10px 0;" href="http://webpage.co.uk"><strong>PURCHASE</strong></a></p>
</div>

<div class="accordion-button">Find out More ▸</div><div style="display: none;" class="accordion-button-active">Less ▾</div>

</div>
```